# Python - "slashList = [i for i, ind in enumerate(start) if ind == '/']"

Tags: python, for-loop, raspberry-pi, web-crawler

I just started to learn programming 4 weeks ago. I read the book "Learn Python the hard way" and I am currently working through "Learn Raspberry Pi programming with Python". The code that I wrote above completely confuses me and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. The book states it lists the indices of slashes (I am working on a web bot). I just have never seen a format like this in a for loop. Why is there a variable in front of the for? Please explain (in english please:D).

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Its called list comprehension, I think you will find handsome amount of text explaining that in the internet.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a list comprehension, a more compact way of running a loop to build up a list in Python.

The long way of writing this would be:

```
SlashList = []
for i, ind in enumerate(start):
    If ind == '/':
       SlashList.append(i)
```

Where ind is the name for the value of the field in list 'start' and i is ind's index (or position in the list)

And 'ind' and 'start' being particularly unhelpful variable names likely adds to the confusion in understanding the line :-)

Comment: Thank you very much this really helped.  So basically if start would be an URL, enumerate would assign a number to every character in the URL and the the for loop iterates then over i (number) and ind (character) is this correct?

Comment: yes, but note that enumerate works on lists, not strings, so then start would have to be a list to use enumerate, not a string. Perhaps somewhere higher in your code the string url is being turned into a list. If start is a string then you can turn it into a list of its characters very easily with:  list(start) -- so doing that on the fly in your above code would be like: for i, ind in enumerate(list(start)):

Answer (score 0):

A "for loop" inside brackets is called "list comprehension".

Here it iterates over `enumerate(start)` which is an iterator yielding a tuple of (index, item) for each item of the iterable given.

This iterator is iterated over, putting index into `i` and the character into `ind` (which is confusing, variable-wise). For each item, if it is a `/`, the index is taken over into the final list so that, at the end, the list consists of all indexes of the slashes in the string(?) `start`.

Answer (score 0):

It does the same thing as the following code:

```
slashList = []
i = 0
for ind in start:
    if ind == '/':
        slashList.append(i)
    i += 1
```

It uses a few tricks to squeeze that all on to one line. The first is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It lets you make a list without breaking out a `for` loop and `if` statement onto different lines. The second is the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) built-in function. It lets you get the index `i` of every item in an iterable like `start` at the same time as the item (here, assigned to `ind`) itself.